# replace a string within file using python

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting an odd problem. when I am trying to replace a string in a file.
The relevant line in the file is:

```
 lattice parameter A  [a.u.] 
    5.771452243459
```

and I am trying to replace it as:

```
   with open(newsys, "r+") as finp:
        for line in finp:
            # print(line)
            if line.startswith("lattice parameter A  [a.u.]"):
                line = next(finp)
                print(line)
                print(Alat)
                line.replace(line.strip(), str(Alat))
                print(line)
```

the last 3 print statement gives:

```
    5.771452243459  # string that will be replaced

6.63717007997785    #value of Alat
    5.771452243459  #the line after replace statement
```

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace` method does not modify existing string. Instead it is creating a new one. So in line

```
line.replace(line.strip(), str(Alat))
```

You are creating a completely new string and discards it (because not assign to any variable).

I would do something like:

```
   with open(newsys, "r+") as finp:
        with open('newfile', 'w') as fout:
            for line in finp:
                # print(line)
                if line.startswith("lattice parameter A  [a.u.]"):
                    line = next(finp)
                    print(line)
                    print(Alat)
                    line = line.replace(line.strip(), str(Alat))
                    print(line)
                fout.write(line)
```